# Correct usage of jupyter CLI parameter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

***Disclaimer***: *I use `jupyter kernel`, but the question is also relevant for `jupyter notebook`.*

According to `jupyter kernel --help-all`, I should be able to change the jupyter kernel JSON connection file by setting a parameter called `--KernelManager.connection_file`.

If I understand this correctly, that means that the following command:

```
jupyter kernel --KernelManager.connection_file=connection.json
```

should start a kernel and give me a connection file called *connection.json*.

However, this is what I get:

```
→ jupyter kernel --KernelManager.connection_file='test-this-thing.json'
[KernelApp] Starting kernel 'python3'
[KernelApp] Connection file: /Users/me/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-1e65d0fe-bf8e-1234-8208-463bd4a1234a.json
```

Now, jupyter doesn't complain that I've passed a wrong argument nor anything, it just doesn't change the connection file.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I correctly change the connection filename?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, nothing you are doing in the above code is wrong. Previously the kernel overrode whatever you set as the connection file with a hard coded file location.

This has now been fixed as per the following pull requests:

- https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/pull/399

  - *Removed the static connection file name declaration on kernelapp initialize method.*
- https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/pull/432

  - *Set the default connection_file such that it preserves an existing configuration.*

Answer (score 1):

I useful workaround to set the connection file is to not call `jupyter kernel` directly, but rather use the kernel manager module, which is more flexible:

```
python -m ipykernel_launcher -f ~/kernels/file.json
```

The above works for current and previous versions of jupyter, so I'd consider it to be more reliable.